# Hiding lines in ScintillaNET control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scintilla

I'm using the following code to hide lines in my scintillaNET control:

```
if (cShowProcess.SelectedItem != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < scintilla1.Lines.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!scintilla1.Lines[i].Text.Contains(cShowProcess.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            scintilla1.Lines.Hide(scintilla1.Lines[i].Number,scintilla1.Lines[i].Number);
            //scintilla1.Lines[i].IsVisible = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine and actually hides the lines, however it leaves a space where 
the lines are hidden (i.e. CR) on all hidden lines, is there any way to hide the hidden lines completely?

Comment: The term is "folding".  Docs are not great but here's something: http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Folding